# How can I remove invalid child nodes in a tree

Tags: java

I have below `Tree` class with the following attributes and their getters and setters.

```
public class Tree {
   private String name, address;
   private List<Tree> child; 
}
```

I am iterating a `Tree` and comparing the name with a list of valid names. If the name is not valid, I have to remove that specific `Tree` node from the main `Tree`. However, I don't know how to implement the remove functionality.

```
private void validateTree(Tree tree) {
    if (tree.getChild() != null && !tree.getChild().isEmpty()) {
        for(Tree node:tree.getChild()){
            if(list.contains(node.getName())){  // String elements in list
                validateTree(tree); // validate the subtree
            } else {
                // Here I have to remove the child node from the Tree.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us your code please?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Please add the full source code you currently have, which include the code which doesn't work, to your question.

Comment: Added my validateTree method. I am not getting how to remove elements from Tree if it is not matching with criteria.

Comment: what is that variable list, I can't see it declared what is the  type.

Comment: It is ArrayList containing String Values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a `removeChild()` method in your `Tree`:

```
public class Tree {

    List<Tree> child;

    public void removeChild(Tree tree) {
        child.remove(tree);
    }
}
```

In your validation method you can use it:

```
 if (validNodes.contains(node.getName())) {
    validateTree(tree);
 } else {
    tree.removeChild(node);
 }
```

However, **you should always be *very suspicious* when you are changing a collection that you are looping over**. I would strongly suggest to leave the original `Tree` as is, and create a second, valid, `Tree` that only contains the valid nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The safe way to remove an element from a collection is using iterator. In your case it may look like this:

```
List<Tree> children = tree.getChild();
for (Iterator<Tree> iterator = children.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    Tree node = iterator.next();
    if (list.contains(node.getName())){  // String elements in list
        validateTree(tree); //OK
    } else {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```